# URL requests No connection adapters were found for, error in Python

Tags: url, request

Hi I don't know how to get out of this. I tried to strip this code already with .strip("',()") and make a string out of the tuple object, but it still runs the same error.

```
indir = '/home/d/Desktop/civiv_hacking/Streetnames/dump/berlin.kauperts.de/Strassen'
for root, dirs, filenames in os.walk(indir):
  for f in filenames:
   x = urlparse.urljoin("https://berlin.kauperts.de/Strassen/", f+".html"),
     print(f),
     print(x),
       for r in requests.get(x):'
```

print(x) gives `('https://berlin.kauperts.de/Strassen/Igelsteig-12557-Berlin.html',)`
However if I do: `x1 = (str(x).strip("(),'")),` it gives `https://berlin.kauperts.de/Strassen/Igelsteig-12557-Berlin.html`

But I still always get the same error:

```
in get_adapter raise InvalidSchema("No connection adapters were found for '%s'" % url)
requests.exceptions.InvalidSchema: No connection adapters were found for '('https://berlin.kauperts.de/Strassen/Igelsteig-12557-Berlin.html',)'
```

Does anyone knows a way out of this?
Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Of course also `x1 = (str(x).translate(None, "(),'"))` doesn't do anything good to that.